# WSO2 Governance Cluster Repository location?

Tags: wso2

We have setup WSO2 Governance 4.6 in cluster mode. The registry is connected to an Oracle database, but we see a repository location on file system. Is this the location where all wsdl's, xsd's, etc will be stored?

If yes, does it need to be in a shared file system location between two servers in the cluster & which config files to be edited?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to have a shared location between servers, The artifacts will be automatically synchronized across. Please cross check the settings with the official document that published for [WSO2 Greg clustering](https://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+Governance+Registry)